# When I'm using a list outline in Word, I want to change what style gets used when I backspace once

Tags: microsoft-word, styles, microsoft-word-2016

I think this is the right exchange for this.

I've got an outline for a policy document I'm drafting. When I'm typing the name of a particular heading, if I hit enter, I want the next line to be the same heading level style that I'm currently using. From there, if I Tab or Shift + Tab, I can promote or demote as I like.

However, if I'm in a heading style and I hit backspace once, I want to keep my exact formatting **but lose the heading formatting**. How do I set that up?

Edit: pictures for illustration

Here I have one heading. Note the grey triangle.

[image: First heading]

If I press enter once, it creates a new heading, which I want.

[image: After enter once]

After I then press backspace once, it removes the numbering but keeps the heading, which I don't want.

[image: After backspace, what currently happens]

I want it to get rid of the number and the heading, but keep everything else the same.

[image: After backspace, what I want to happen]

Comment: Have you already configured the style so that Enter sets "the next line to be the same heading level style that I'm currently using"?

Comment: Regarding the main question, do you want backspace to clear the formatting on a blank line? In other words, do you want backspace to clear formatting instead of deleting the new paragraph you just created? Could you include a screenshot of the scenario you are describing with paragraph/formatting marks showing (use CTRL + * to toggle them) and an indication of the cursor position?

Comment: @PFitz I edited the question, hopefully the pictures make sense. Let me know if they're not clear.

Comment: @PFitz Have you had a chance to take a look at this?

Comment: Are you looking to have new line change it's actual formatting, the style tag, or both? Either way, each of the styles being shown in the quick access toolbar is already mapped to a shortcut key so using that would be roughly same number of keystrokes.

Comment: Just create a new style and assign a shortcut key to it.  The result of selecting backspace is not a modifiable action.  It does what it does (removes the numbering but keeps the heading).  If you hit backspace again, it removes the previous paragraph mark and moves the heading text to the line above it.


For shortcut keys linked to styles, I normally use Alt+[any character not used for other commands].

Comment: I could've sworn that I've had Word documents where there's numbering/multilevel lists attached to headings that, when I pressed backspace, it kept the formatting but removed the headingness. It's possible I'm making it up, though.